# REGEX to match countof digit equal with alphabet in a string

Tags: regex

Just checking if it's possible to use regex to validate/check a string of alphanumeric to ensure it has same total of digit and alphabet.

For example,

```
7868HGCD (4 digits, 4 alphabets)
87429AJIGH (5 digits, 5 alphabets)
8A2K9H7A (digits ,alphabets alternately)
1H2B3C7D9K8L
```

..and the list goes on.

Any syntax is okay just as long the digit and alphabets in a string are equal in total. I tried `^([a-zA-Z0-9 -]+)$` which accepts alphanumeric, but I don't know what regex can be use to check (total digits = total alphabets)

Using a lookahead `^(?=[^\s]?[0-9])(?=[^\s]?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` but it finds all strings which have at least one letter and one number.

Comment: I don't think regexes are the tool to use here. What you are trying to do breaks the rules of a regular language.

Comment: You can't really count with regular expressions - use your programming language of choice for this.

Comment: @Jan You can't count with regex, but you sure can count _on_ them LOL.  Regex saves the day!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this using pure regex, but if you are using regex along with an application language, then this problem is straightforward.  For example, in Java we can try:

```
String input = "7868HGCD";
if (input.replaceAll("[A-Z]", "").length() ==
    input.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").length()) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
else {
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```

The idea here is to use regex to strip letters or numbers, alternatively, and then compare the remaining lengths of each.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put my two cents in: you could write yourself a small parser, e.g. in `Python`:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor
from parsimonious.exceptions import ParseError

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    term        = (digit / alpha)+
    digit       = ~"\d"
    alpha       = ~"[a-zA-Z]"
    """)

class AlnumCounter(NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.abc = 0
        self.digits = 0

    def visit_digit(self, node, children):
        self.digits += 1

    def visit_alpha(self, node, children):
        self.abc += 1

    def visit_term(self, node, children):
        return (self.digits, self.abc)

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return node or visited_children

# list of strings
strings = ['7868HGCD', '87429AJIGH', '8A2K9H7A', '1H2B3C7D9K8L', 'somegarbage', 'parsing error']

alnum = AlnumCounter()
for string in strings:
    try:
        tree = grammar.parse(string)
        out = alnum.visit(tree)

        if out[0] == out[1]:
            print("Correct format: {}".format(string))
        else:
            print("Not correct: {}".format(string))

    except ParseError:
        print("Encountered strange characters within '{}'".format(string))

    finally:
        # reset the counters
        alnum.reset()
```

This would yield

```
Correct format: 7868HGCD
Correct format: 87429AJIGH
Correct format: 8A2K9H7A
Correct format: 1H2B3C7D9K8L
Not correct: somegarbage
Encountered strange characters within 'parsing error'
```

Comment: Crazy, but probably the most efficient way to solve this problem +1 (regex always incurs an overhead)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution using JavaScript `match` method.

```js
var str = '7868HGCD';

console.log(str.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).length == str.match(/[0-9]/g).length);
```